# How to redirect to the same view using ModelAndview in Spring MVC framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a page with a link. On clicking the link a page opens up in a separate window. This new page has a form. On submitting this form, some operation takes place at the server. The result of which needs to be redirected to the same page. However after the operation on using the following:

> return new ModelAndView("newUser");
>   //This view "newUser" actually maps to the popped up window.

A similar new window again pops up and the message gets displayed on this new page.
Any ideas as to why this behavior or how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open a popup window with a form in it, any submits from here to the server will be handled in the same location, so you will get your response (and any subsequent request-responses) in that popup window.

If I understand this right, you have a page X which opens the popup, you submit in the popup and as a result you want again the content of page X, but in the popup?

If that is the case I thing the behavior is not from Spring but from what you have in the X page. Maybe a JavaScript which gets triggered on load and opens a new popup? Can't really tell without seeing more code.

Comment: As you have mentioned, the flow is like this .
I have a page X which opens a popup.
I submit in the popup. I expect the result of the operation of the submission in the pop up, for that I redirect to the same pop up page, but the redirection gives another pop up with the result.
I dont quite understand why this is so... :(

Comment: Do you by any chance have a target="_blank" on the form in the popup? Do you use JavaScript in your pages and somehow interact with the form submission or result? I can't tell from just the behavior.

Comment: Thanks.. It was an old code.. and I just checked to find one.. :)